# Add required date picker to shopify product page

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I added a date input as block to a Shopify product template. It works and the data addeed to it appears in the properties of the product, when in cart and ordered.

But I can't get the input to be required here.

Important to note: This ist NOT to add a delivery date. The product is a course and the buyer need to choose the date of participation.

I've added the `required` attribute to the input element and also added an `required` as class.

Markup in `main-product.liquid`

```
<date-picker class="date_picker">
  <label 
    for="course-date-{{ section.id }}"
    class="date_picker__label form__label"
  >
    {{- 'products.product.course_date' | t -}}
  </label>

  <div class="date_picker__input-wrapper">
    <input
      type="date" 
      id="course-date-{{ section.id }}"
      class="required date_picker__input"
      name="properties[Kursdatum]"
      min="{{ block.settings.season_date_start }}"
      max="{{ block.settings.season_date_end }}"
      form="{{ product_form_id }}"
      required
    />
  </div>
</date-picker>
```

Comment: Product is added using AJAX cart or a simple page load?

Comment: Sorry, I think I dont get, what you mean. The collection of the form data is working – it's the required value that is ignored. And I can't tell why …

Comment: Is there any working URL of the issue, I can check it?

Comment: Not by now … sorry! But I think I got the problem – I'll update my question, if I'm sure. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Onkar: And I also get now what you meant in your first question: The theme is Dawn and the product is added by a publish function. Prior to this function the content isn't checked so I'll add some JS to do so.